# Can we use a noun after "whenever," "however" and "wherever"?

Tags: word-usage

As you know, after *whatever* and *whichever* we can use a noun e.g, "Whichever one you choose, I'll be OK with it."

I read somewhere when we use a noun as a subject we can put *when-/where-/how- ever* before them, though I can't think of an example.

Comment: "Whenever I speak to him I am amazed by his intellect." "However she dresses she looks stunning". "Wherever I go there is nowhere like home". However the noun is not itself the subject, but part of a modifying clause.

Comment: You give an example of the determiner usage. Another is 'Buy whatever tools you are going to need'. Whenever, however and wherever are not used as determiners. The examples @WS2 gives above are quite different.

Comment: Note the different ways the words are used as shown by the comments above.

Comment: 'Whatever day we meet, whichever place we meet in and whatever method of combat he chooses, I shall be ready for him.' I could not say 'whenever day' nor 'wherever place' nor 'however method'.